# Count entries in a for loop and then use integer to format excel spreadsheet vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, for-loop, datatable

I am currently exporting to an excel sheet from a datatable in VB.NET. I want to format the cells and I am trying to do this using an integer based variable to select the max rows I am using per download. The problem is trying to carry the number of times the for loop ran, or the rows of the datatable, over to the format section of the code. Code example:

```
        Dim EffMaxCellX As Integer
        Dim EffmaxcellY As Integer
        Dim JobsMaxCellX As Integer
        Dim JobsMaxCellY As Integer

        For I = 0 To dtEff.Rows.Count - 1
            For J = 0 To dtEff.Columns.Count - 1
                xlworksheet.Cells(1, J + 1) = dtEff.Columns(J).ToString
                xlworksheet.Cells(I + 2, J + 1) = dtEff.Rows(I).Item(J).ToString
                EffMaxCellX = I
                EffmaxcellY = J
            Next
        Next

        For I = 0 To dtJobs.Rows.Count - 1
            For J = 0 To dtJobs.Columns.Count - 1
                xlworksheet.Cells(1, J + 8) = dtJobs.Columns(J).ToString
                xlworksheet.Cells(I + 2, J + 8) = dtJobs.Rows(I).Item(J).ToString
                JobsMaxCellX = I
                JobsMaxCellY = J
            Next
        Next


        '--------------Format excel sheet----------
        Dim formatRange As excel.Range
        formatRange = xlworksheet.Range("a1")
        formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
        formatRange.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)

        Dim FormatRangeBorderEff As excel.Range
        FormatRangeBorderEff = xlworksheet.Range("A1", "F" & EffMaxCellX.ToString & "")
        FormatRangeBorderEff.BorderAround(excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)

        Dim FormatRangeBorderJobs As excel.Range
        FormatRangeBorderJobs = xlworksheet.Range("H1", "J" & JobsMaxCellX.ToString & "")
        FormatRangeBorderJobs.BorderAround(excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)
```

In the code above I am looping through two datatable and then using the integers and attempting to build them into the excel format code. Can I do this or do I need to find another method? The code bugs on

```
 FormatRangeBorderEff = xlworksheet.Range("A0", "F" & EffMaxCellX.ToString & "")
```

Comment: There is no cell A0 or H0. Try A1 and H1

Comment: I changed them over to A1 and H1 but I am still getting the error, let me grab the name of the error real quick.

Comment: Also, this `"F" & EffMaxCellX.ToString & ""` can be this `"F" & EffMaxCellX`.  When concatenating any number there is implicit conversion to string.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact I am trying to build the integer with the & and &.

Comment: When setting a range you have to use 'set'.  Try `Set FormatRangeBorderEff = xlworksheet.Range("A1", "F" & EffMaxCellX)`

Comment: can you try this xlworksheet.Range("A1", "F8") and tell me if it works?

Comment: I have tried removing the "tostring" and it is still bugging, The error is "sytem.runtime.interopservices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Comment: My bad I thought this was VBA

Comment: @Claudius Yes this does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I will try to fix it with this code

```
Dim EffMaxCellX, EffmaxcellY, JobsMaxCellX, JobsMaxCellY As Integer

    For i = 0 To dtEff.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To dtEff.Columns.Count - 1
            xlworksheet.Cells(1, j + 1) = dtEff.Columns(j).ToString
            xlworksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dtEff.Rows(i).Item(j).ToString
            EffMaxCellX = i 
            EffmaxcellY = j
        Next
    Next

    For x = 0 To dtJobs.Rows.Count - 1
        For z = 0 To dtJobs.Columns.Count - 1
            xlworksheet.Cells(1, z + 8) = dtJobs.Columns(z).ToString
            xlworksheet.Cells(x + 2, z + 8) = dtJobs.Rows(x).Item(z).ToString
            JobsMaxCellX = x
            JobsMaxCellY = z
        Next
    Next


    '--------------Format excel sheet----------

Dim FormatRangeBorderJobs, formatRange, FormatRangeBorderEff As excel.Range

    formatRange = xlworksheet.Range("a1")
    formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
    formatRange.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)


    FormatRangeBorderEff = xlworksheet.Range("A1", String.Format("F{0}",  EffMaxCellX.ToString)
    FormatRangeBorderEff.BorderAround(excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)


    FormatRangeBorderJobs = xlworksheet.Range("H1", String.Format("J{0}", JobsMaxCellX.ToString)
    FormatRangeBorderJobs.BorderAround(excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)
```

Cleaner version:

```
Dim EffMaxCellX, EffmaxcellY, JobsMaxCellX, JobsMaxCellY As Integer
        For i = 0 To dtEff.Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To dtEff.Columns.Count - 1
                xlworksheet.Cells(1, j + 1) = dtEff.Columns(j).ToString
                xlworksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dtEff.Rows(i).Item(j).ToString
            Next
    Next

    For x = 0 To dtJobs.Rows.Count - 1
        For z = 0 To dtJobs.Columns.Count - 1
            xlworksheet.Cells(1, z + 8) = dtJobs.Columns(z).ToString
            xlworksheet.Cells(x + 2, z + 8) = tJobs.Rows(x).Item(z).ToString
        Next
    Next
            EffMaxCellX = dtEff.Rows.Count - 1 
            EffmaxcellY = dtEff.Columns.Count - 1 
            JobsMaxCellX = dtJobs.Rows.Count -1
            JobsMaxCellY = dtJobs.Columns.Count -1
```

' I believe you are making a mistake in the above code but it is no different that the one you had

```
    '--------------Format excel sheet----------

Dim  formatRange As excel.Range

    formatRange = xlworksheet.Range("a1")
    formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
    formatRange.EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)

    GetBorder("A1", String.Format("F{0}",  EffMaxCellX.ToString)
    GetBorder("H1", String.Format("J{0}", JobsMaxCellX.ToString)

Sub GetBorder(ByVal startCell as String, ByVal endCell as String)
        Dim FormatRangeBorderEff As excel.Range
        FormatRangeBorderEff = xlworksheet.Range(startCell, endCell)
        FormatRangeBorderEff.BorderAround(excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)
End Sub
```

Comment: just got back to this at work today, let me give it a shot

Comment: this code does appear to work, I will upload a solution.

Comment: It did work but there are some other things I want to cover in the solution. Im busy with some other stuff at work right now but ill be sure to update on my lunch break.

Comment: Do you have problems in anything else?

Comment: nope, i got it going now. thanks so much for the help.